# DOM manipulation in the puppeteer page.evaluation

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Inside of a PuppeteerJS `page.evaluate()` function. I need to find some element with class "sblack" inside the sibling element.
Can somebody help with next issue:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.result-main').forEach(function(element) {
    let nextEl =  element.nextElementSibling.querySelectorAll('.sblack')[0].innerText;
    matches.push({
        _id: element.querySelector('.bet-number').innerText,
        bet_date: element.querySelector('.date').textContent,
        matchDate: nextEl
    });
});
```

I receive an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined", but I expected to receive the text inside the element with class "sblack".

Comment: Have you tried running that code in a normal browser console? The code looks right. I suspect that a class name is incorrect... You may also want to try waiting for some time until the page fully loads with `await page.goto('...', {"waitUntil" : "networkidle0"});`

Comment: yes, I am using page.goto('...', {"waitUntil" : "networkidle0"})

Comment: One sure thing is that `element.nextElementSibling.querySelectorAll('.sblack')[0]` does not exist. Could you return early with `return element.nextElementSibling.toString()` and print that in the console to see what you get?

Comment: I understood that it does not exist, but why?
element.nextElementSibling.toString() return  '[object HTMLTableRowElement]

Comment: Yes, that may be a bit strange. You are close to the solution though. It seems that `element.nextElementSibling` exist. Therefore the issue is at `querySelectorAll`. A few recomendations: Run Puppeteer in `headless` mode `false` to see the screen and `console.log` every step. Also, bear in mind how `querySelectorAll` behaves differently: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll. You can also simply inject jQuery into Puppeteer and use something like `$('.result-main .sblack').innerText`. Actually, chances are that jQuery is already there.

Comment: thanks, @adelriosantiago for help. I used 'puppeteer.launch({devtools: true})' and added 'debbuger'. After debugging I found a mistake in my layout, now my code works as expected.

Comment: So can you post the solution? :D

Comment: the posted code works correctly, the problem was in the file that I opened